# Rule Syntax for Azure user.memberof

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, entra, azure-entra-id

I'm trying to create a dynamic group with a dynamic membership rule that adds a user who are not part of a another group.

so based on documentation `user.memberof -any (group.objectId -in ['my-group-id'])` works but I'm trying to modify it. `-not (user.memberof -any (group.objectId -in ['my-group-id'])` Have tried this but will give an invalid property same goes if I modify `(group.objectId -not ['my-group-id'])` gives an invalid operand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in this **[MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/users/groups-dynamic-rule-member-of#preview-limitations)**, there is a **limitation** saying:

> The <kbd>memberOf</kbd> attribute can't be used with other operators. For example, you can't create a rule that states *“Members Of group A can't be in Dynamic group B.”*

I have one group created with dynamic query **`user.department -eq "IT"`** having below users as members:

[image]

Now, I created new **dynamic group** by including same members of above group with this dynamic query:

```
user.memberof -any (group.objectId -in ['above-group-id'])
```

[image]

When I tried to modify the dynamic query to exclude the members present in another group, I too got **same errors** like this:

```
-not (user.memberof -any (group.objectId -in ['my-group-id']))
```

[image]

```
user.memberof -any (group.objectId -not ['my-group-id'])
```

[image]

So, it's **not possible** to exclude the members of specific group while creating dynamic group with <kbd>memberOf</kbd> attribute.

> Alternatively, you can **filter** out users based on their properties like department, companyName, jobTitle, city, country etc....

When I modified the dynamic query to **`user.department -ne "IT"`** based on user property, it worked:

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the group members where users from **`DemoGrp01`** excluded successfully like this:

[image]

**Reference:**
[Exclude user from a dynamic group based on group membership - Microsoft Q&A by **Aaron Gill**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1063551/exclude-user-from-a-dynamic-group-based-on-group-m)